# A cart with identifier 1 was already stored

Tags: laravel, e-commerce

I'm trying to follow a tutorial I found on youtube using bumbummen99's shopping cart package about storing instances into the database, but I'm getting an error that it can't store the cart using the same identifier.

Here's the code when I'm storing the instance:

```
public function render()
         ...
        if(Auth::check()){
            Cart::instance('cart')->store(Auth::user()->id);
        }
```

Since the instance is getting stored before I can add a product to the cart, it doesn't save the product inside the cart after logging out.

Answer (score 1):

With the fact i have only minor experiences with persistent shopping carts, i found it weird it didn't have an `update()` method.

In your case, i would assume you should `erase()` the cart before saving it again, to ensure the correct cart is in the database.

```
Cart::instance('cart')->erase(Auth::user()->id);
Cart::instance('cart')->store(Auth::user()->id);
```

In general saving the cart seems like a challenge, i would assume the best practice is to save on logouts, as the session will persist and this should not be done in context of render calls. Or with a button to actually save the state of the cart for later.